# Slice multi-index pandas dataframe by date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice, multi-index

Say I have the following multi-index dataframe:

```
arrays = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo']),
          pd.to_datetime(['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-04', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-04'])]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((8, 4)), index=arrays)

                 0    1    2    3
bar 2020-01-01  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
    2020-01-02  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
    2020-01-03  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
    2020-01-04  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
foo 2020-01-01  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
    2020-01-02  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
    2020-01-03  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
    2020-01-04  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

How do I select only the part of this dataframe where the first index `level = 'bar'`, and `date > 2020.01.02`, such that I can add 1 to this part?

To be clearer, the expected output would be:

```
                 0    1    2    3
bar 2020-01-01  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
    2020-01-02  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
    2020-01-03  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
    2020-01-04  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
foo 2020-01-01  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
    2020-01-02  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
    2020-01-03  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
    2020-01-04  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

I managed slicing it according to the first index:

```
df.loc['bar']
```

But then I am not able to apply the condition on the date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is possible compare each level and then set `1`, there is `:` for all columns in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
m1 = df.index.get_level_values(0) =='bar' 
m2 = df.index.get_level_values(1) > '2020-01-02'

df.loc[m1 & m2, :] = 1
print (df)

                  0    1    2    3
bar 2020-01-01  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
    2020-01-02  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
    2020-01-03  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
    2020-01-04  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
foo 2020-01-01  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
    2020-01-02  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
    2020-01-03  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
    2020-01-04  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#give your index names :
df.index = df.index.set_names(["names","dates"])

#get the indices that match your condition
index = df.query('names=="bar" and dates>"2020-01-02"').index

#assign 1 to the relevant points
#IndexSlice makes slicing multiindexes easier ... here though, it might be seen as overkill
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[idx[index],:] = 1


                 0  1   2   3
names   dates               
bar 2020-01-01  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
    2020-01-02  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
    2020-01-03  1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
    2020-01-04  1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
foo 2020-01-01  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
    2020-01-02  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
    2020-01-03  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
    2020-01-04  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to parametrize `IndexSlice` directly without a need to run `query` (like in @sammywemmy answer, and you don't need to name your index cols):

```py
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[idx["bar", dt.datetime(2020, 1, 3):], :] = 1

df
#                  0    1    2    3
# bar 2020-01-01  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
#     2020-01-02  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
#     2020-01-03  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
#     2020-01-04  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
# foo 2020-01-01  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
#     2020-01-02  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
#     2020-01-03  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
#     2020-01-04  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

With this approach, you can easily change your parametrization:

1. Do the same for both "bar" and "foo":

```py
df.loc[idx[("bar", "foo"), dt.datetime(2020, 1, 3):], :] = 1
```

2. Use strings instead of datetime objects:

```py
df.loc[idx["bar", "2020-01-03":], :] = 1
```

3. Add upper bound for date filter:

```py
df.loc[idx["bar", dt.datetime(2020, 1, 2):dt.datetime(2020, 1, 3)], :] = 1
```

4. Change single row instead of slice/date-range:

```py
df.loc[idx["bar", dt.datetime(2020, 1, 3)], :] = 1
```